# Perceptron Learning Algorithm taking a lot of iterations to converge?

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, perceptron

I am solving the homework-1 of Caltech Machine Learning Course (http://work.caltech.edu/homework/hw1.pdf) . To solve ques 7-10 we need to implement a PLA. This is my implementation in python:

```
import sys,math,random

w=[] # stores the weights
data=[] # stores the vector X(x1,x2,...)
output=[] # stores the output(y)


# returns 1 if dot product is more than 0
def sign_dot_product(x):
    global w
    dot=sum([w[i]*x[i] for i in xrange(len(w))])
    if(dot>0):
        return 1
    else :
        return -1

# checks if a point is misclassified
def is_misclassified(rand_p):
    return (True if sign_dot_product(data[rand_p])!=output[rand_p] else False)


# loads data in the following format:
# x1 x2 ... y
# In the present case for d=2
# x1 x2 y
def load_data():
    f=open("data.dat","r")
    global w
    for line in f:
        data_tmp=([1]+[float(x) for x in line.split(" ")])
        data.append(data_tmp[0:-1])
        output.append(data_tmp[-1])


def train():
    global w
    w=[ random.uniform(-1,1) for i in xrange(len(data[0]))] # initializes w with random weights
    iter=1
    while True:

        rand_p=random.randint(0,len(output)-1) # randomly picks a point
        check=[0]*len(output) # check is a list. The ith location is 1 if the ith point is correctly classified
        while not is_misclassified(rand_p):
            check[rand_p]=1
            rand_p=random.randint(0,len(output)-1)
            if sum(check)==len(output):
                print "All points successfully satisfied in ",iter-1," iterations"
                print iter-1,w,data[rand_p]
                return iter-1
        sign=output[rand_p]
        w=[w[i]+sign*data[rand_p][i] for i in xrange(len(w))] # changing weights
        if iter>1000000:
            print "greater than 1000"
            print w
            return 10000000
        iter+=1

load_data()

def simulate():
   #tot_iter=train()
    tot_iter=sum([train() for x in xrange(100)])
    print float(tot_iter)/100

simulate()
```

The problem according to the answer of question 7 it should take around `15 iterations` for perceptron to converge when size of training set but the my implementation  takes a average of `50000 iteration` . The training data is to be randomly generated but I am generating data for simple lines such as x=4,y=2,..etc. Is this the reason why I am getting wrong answer or there is something else wrong. Sample of my training data(separable using y=2):

```
1 2.1 1
231 100 1
-232 1.9 -1
23 232 1
12 -23 -1
10000 1.9 -1
-1000 2.4 1
100 -100 -1
45 73 1
-34 1.5 -1
```

It is in the format `x1 x2 output(y)`

Answer (score 4):

It is clear that you are doing a great job learning both Python and classification algorithms with your effort.

However, because of some of the stylistic inefficiencies with your code, it makes it difficult to help you and it creates a chance that part of the problem could be a miscommunication between you and the professor.

For example, does the professor wish for you to use the Perceptron in "online mode" or "offline mode"? In "online mode" you should move sequentially through the data point and you should not revisit any points. From the assignment's conjecture that it should require only 15 iterations to converge, I am curious if this implies the first 15 data points, in sequential order, would result in a classifier that linearly separates your data set.

By instead sampling randomly with replacement, you might be causing yourself to take much longer (although, depending on the distribution and size of the data sample, this is admittedly unlikely since you'd expect roughly that any 15 points would do about as well as the first 15).

The other issue is that after you detect a correctly classified point (cases when `not is_misclassified` evaluates to `True`) if you then witness a new random point that *is* misclassified, then your code will kick down into the larger section of the outer `while` loop, and then go back to the top where it will overwrite the `check` vector with all 0s.

This means that the only way your code will detect that it has correctly classified all the points is if the particular random sequence that it evaluates them (in the inner `while` loop) happens to be a string of all 1's except for the miraculous ability that on any particular 0, *on that pass through the array*, it classifies correctly.

I can't quite formalize why I think that will make the program take much longer, but it seems like your code is requiring a much stricter form of convergence, where it sort of has to learn everything all at once on one monolithic pass way late in the training stage after having been updated a bunch already.

One easy way to check if my intuition about this is crappy would be to move the line `check=[0]*len(output)` outside of the `while loop` all together and only initialize it one time.

Some general advice to make the code easier to manage:

1. Don't use global variables. Instead, let your function to load and prep the data return things.
2. There are a few places where you say, for example,

   `return (True if sign_dot_product(data[rand_p])!=output[rand_p] else False)`

   This kind of thing can be simplified to

   `return sign_dot_product(data[rand_p]) != output[rand_p]`

   which is easier to read and conveys what criteria you're trying to check for in a more   direct manner.
3. I doubt efficiency plays an important role since this seems to be a pedagogical exercise, but there are a number of ways to refactor your use of list comprehensions that might be beneficial. And if possible, just use `NumPy` which has native array types. Witnessing how some of these operations have to be expressed with `list` operations is lamentable. Even if your professor doesn't want you to implement with `NumPy` because she or he is trying to teach you pure fundamentals, I say just ignore them and go learn `NumPy`. It will help you with jobs, internships, and practical skill with these kinds of manipulations in Python vastly more than fighting with the native data types to do something they were not designed for (array computing).

Comment: First of all thanks for the feedback. I am actually not enrolled in the course but doing a bit of self learning. The algorithm I used can be viewed in slide 14 in http://www.amlbook.com/slides/iTunesU_Lecture01_April_03.pdf. Here it is given to pick the new point with replacement. And the homework talks about the same PLA algorithm. So according to the text is there any problem with my implementation or data set generating the problem.

Comment: Without seeing all of the data generation code, I can't say much more. It seems like you should not be using the `check` variable, and instead you should just use `pass` or `continue` whenever, after generating a new `rand_p` it is correctly classified. Try that, and try just walking sequentially through the data (even if you wrap around and start back at the beginning of the data again). Just see how long that takes. From the code I can see, other than this issue of taking a long time, I don't see anything algorithmically wrong. The use of global variables complicates it though.